# JTextField getText () after a space

Tags: java, mysql, jtextfield

I'm making something like a MySql console  using Java.

I have two JtextFields. One For the Main Command and the second for command parameters.

I, m trying to make a command`select`, which will select the given data from the given SQL table and print it in JTextArea.
I already did that,but for every table I have to write an `public void`.

My question is, can I make the void get the second word from JtextField.

As example: If I have the command `select test`, I want the `publc void` to excute TheSQL command as: `SELECT * FROM test` . But if I replace `test` with something else, i want  getText () but after the space, so it has to get the text after select.

`JTextDield2` Is not usable because there I have to enter the strings for the printing.

My Code:

panel.java

```
package test;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class  panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    protected JTextField textField, textField2;
    protected static JTextArea textArea;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    public panel() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        textField = new JTextField(30);
        textField.addActionListener(this);
        textField.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        textField2 = new JTextField(30);
        textField2.addActionListener(this);
        textField2.setEnabled(false);

        textArea = new MyTextArea(30, 100);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
       // textArea.setBackground(new Color(1,1,1, (float) 0.01));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);
        add(textField2, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(scrollPane, c);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("connect")){
            textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            textField.setText("");
        }else if(textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("select test")){
            textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            viewTest(conn);
            textField.setText("");;
        }else if(textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("clear")){
            textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            textField.setText("");
            clear();
        }else if(textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("commands")){
            textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            commandsmenu();
            textField.setText("");
        }else if(textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("insertinto")){
            textField2.setEnabled(true);
            if(textField2.getText().isEmpty()){
            textArea.append("Please add the VALUES of the table on the second textfield! Syntax: 'Agevaulue', namevalue, adressvalue !" + newline);
            }else{

                textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                InsertInto(conn);
                textField2.setText("");
                textField2.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }else if(textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("createtable")){
            if(textField2.getText().isEmpty()){
                textArea.append("Please add the Command parameters on the Secont textField!" + newline + "SYNTAX: tablename(c, c, c)VALUES('num', ''text''");
                textField2.setEnabled(true);
            }else {
                textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                CreateTable(conn);
                textField2.setEnabled(false);
                textField2.setText("");
            }
        }else if(textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            textField.setVisible(true);
        }



        else {
            clear();
            textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
            textArea.append("Uknown Command -- use: commands --  to see all commands!" + newline);
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java + MySQL Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new panel());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

     public Connection conn;{
            try
            {
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://sql5.freemysqlhosting.net/sql555081";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sql555081", "yT6%qQ7%");


            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
    public void viewTest(Connection conn)
          {
            try{

            String query = "SELECT * FROM test";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()){
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String adress = rs.getString("adress");
                textArea.append("AGE: " + age + " |Name: " + name + " |Adress: " + adress + newline);
            } 
          }catch(Exception e){
              textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
              textArea.append("Got an Exception!" + newline);
              textArea.append(e.getMessage());

          }
            }public void InsertInto(Connection conn) {

                try{
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + textField2.getText());
                    textArea.append("Data Imported!" + newline);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    textArea.append("Got an Exception" + newline);
                    textArea.append(e.getMessage());

                }
            }public void CreateTable(Connection conn) {
                try{
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE" + textField2.getText());
                textArea.append( newline + "Table created!" + newline);
            }catch(Exception e){
                textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
                textArea.append( newline + "Got an Exception" + newline);
                textArea.append(e.getMessage());

            }
            }
    public void clear(){
        textArea.setText("");
    }
    public void commandsmenu() {
        textArea.append("select <table> -  read a <table>" + newline);
        textArea.append("clear - clear output" + newline);
        textArea.append("commands - see Commands" + newline);
        textArea.append("insertinto <table> - insert data into <table>" + newline);
        textArea.append(newline);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyTextArea.java

```
package test;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {

    private Image img;

    public MyTextArea(int a, int b) {
        super(a,b);
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg"));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img,550,200,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code and format it nicely to go with your question.

Comment: Yea as I told I'm traveling for Home now..

Comment: So I'm using StackEx. Mobile app for Android my code is in my PC at Home

Comment: I haven't so many time so I told "I'll edit it when I get Home" later I have to out again..

Comment: Okay, I have removed the downvote. Thank you for clarifying the question nicely.